# Slim Framework: create reference to raw post/get and run custom escape function

Tags: php, slim

I've searched high and low about this and can't seem to find anything on the subject.

The documentation states that i can obtain a reference to these variables like so:

```
$allGetVars = $app->request->get();
$allPostVars = $app->request->post();
$allPutVars = $app->request->put();
```

what i'm wondering if i can modify them in some way, but i'm not really having any ideas. i'm looking for a good way to modify these arrays and have them reflected in the app, so that later they may be used in the application.

Comment: It doesn't use $_GET or $_POST, it uses the raw query string or input for those, you could extend `Slim` itself, and set up a new request end/or environment (extending the built ins) [in that class](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Slim.php#L159). BTW: you need to unset that one explicitly first, otherwise, `container->singleton()`  does not accept a new value.

Comment: Hm, scratch that, `private` constructor there as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bit of a hack but you can modify `$app->environment["slim.request.query_hash"]` in `slim.before` hook.

```
$app->hook("slim.before", function() use ($app) {

    $hash = $app->environment["slim.request.query_hash"];

    if (isset($hash["foo"])) {
        $hash["foo"] .= "foo";
    }

    $hash["bar"] = "bar";

    $app->environment["slim.request.query_hash"] = $hash;
});
```

Comment: `var_dump($hash);` outputs `NULL`

Comment: should be `$app->environment['PATH_INFO'];` thanks for your help

Comment: I use above code in production. Maybe it depends on environment.